# ASP.NET Authentication issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I get an error on a login function when user does not exist in my database.

Here is my function:

```
private bool AdminIsValid(string username, string password)
{
    using (var db = new AdminEntities())
    {
       return db.users.Any(u => u.password.Trim() == password &&
                                u.uname.Trim() == username);
    }
}
```

It works as intended bu when a user does not exist I get the following error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified).

I suspect the `ApplicationServices` connection string to be the cause of this, you know the one that comes with the template.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
           connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I haven't found a way to get rid off it, When I remove it I get different errors.
When the user log in is valid, then no errors are thrown.

When the password is wrong I get :

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in
>   starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be
>   closed.

Comment: You probably need an if else statement. If the User Exists, proceed on, else show a jQuery popup or change a label text to "Login Unsuccessful" or something of that sort.

Comment: @Humpy, yes I have a condition on the bool that is return, the errors occurs even if I reach the else block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing all `ApplicationServices` connection strings with my own.

Then I ran the following command:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S DBServerName -U DBLogin -P DBPassword -A all -d DBName
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me and it depended on what page it was on. This was because unless simple membership is initialized, the authentication/authorization mechanism would fail and give weird (untrue!) messages.

In my case, adding the attribute [InitializeSimpleMembership] to the Controller class would ensure that the connection had been setup correctly and got rid of the error.

Comment: Its not MVC, how do I use this attribute?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It appears to be my own class I must have got from the web. The code is here http://pastebin.com/t7k8dZjz

Comment: Its a ASP.NET application not an MVC one

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise this code was MVC specific. There is a tutorial here for web pages: http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp-net-webpages/